# Python code caching in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am writing some common functions to use in pl/Python in PostgreSQL.

The python modules are loaded into PL/Python functions by:

```
from sys import path
path.append('/PythonLibrary/PostgreSQL')
from Module import funcA, funcB, etc
```

This works OK until you change the module source code. The server has the code cached, or in a compiled state, but it fails to detect changes and reload.

How is Postgres handling this, and how can I get changes detected and handled appropriately.

Thanks.

Comment: try restarting the server (postgresql)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`reload(module),`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imp.html?highlight=reload#imp.reload) example (Python 3.3):

```
from imp import reload
import my_module
my_module = reload(my_module)
from my_module import my_function
```

In Python 2 `reload()` is a built-in function, in Python 3 it was moved to the `imp` module, in 3.4 and later it is in `importlib`.